How to update the role attribute for ion-segment to radiogroup from tablist and similarly for ion-segment-button from tab to radio for accessibility?
While using ionic segments for options for filters, the UI looks great, however, there is a bug raised on accessibility where the fix suggestion is to update the roles to use radiogroup and radio instead of tablist and tab. Now these are coming directly from the implemented components. Is there a way to override these?
Tried adding role attributes to both the ion-segment and ion-segment-button but doesn't help.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
